# SQLite table in column possible?

Tags: sqlite

Suppose I have a table with the following columns:

```
ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
NAME TEXT,
KEYWORDS TEXT
```

I want KEYWORDS to be a table that can contain zero or more distinct strings. How can I do that? If it's not possible, what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Never store multiple values in one column!

The problem you face is called a *m to n relation*. Use another table with the keywords and a mapping table to relate to your table and the keyword table. Example (I name your first table `articles`)

```
articles table
----------------
ID
NAME

keywords table
--------------
ID
KEYWORD

article_keywords
-------------
ARTICLE_ID
KEYWORD_ID
```